# Static reference to application context and resources in a companion object of Application

Tags: android, kotlin-android-extensions

I've read a number of articles and stackoverflow posts regarding this question (mainly context instead of resources). A lot of people said it's OK because the `Application` class and the application context should always be alive throughout the life of the app, but some still discourage doing this sighting unknown possibilities (which made me doubtful - hence this post).

On the other hand, passing `Context` to every Object's function is quite daunting. In Java, one way to overcome this was to do something like `UtilClass.getInstance(context)` but you can't do that with Kotlin objects and I'm not too sure about implementing [Kotlin Singletons with Arguments](https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/kotlin-singletons-with-argument-194ef06edd9e).

So, I have the following code:

```
class App : MultiDexApplication() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        _resources = resources
        _context = applicationContext

        //..other code
    }

    companion object {
        val resources: Resources
            get() = _resources!!
        val context: Context
            get() = _context!!
        private var _resources: Resources? = null
        private var _context: Context? = null
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm keeping a static reference to the **application context** and **resources** in a `companion object` when onCreate is called. With this, I'm able to (as examples):

- call `App.context` in a util `object` that make API calls with [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion).
- call `App.resources` in a util `object` that uses resource strings.

It's a convenience as compared to passing `Context` and/or `Resources` every time I call an object's method. **Is this a safe solution?** If not, **are there any better alternatives?**